# What is the fastest way to get the result of matrix < matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix `M_1` of dimension (M, A) and a matrix `M_2` of dimension (M, B). The result of `M_1 < M_2` should be a matrix of dimension (M, B, A) where by each row in `M1` is being compared with each element of the corresponding row of `M_2` and give a boolean vector (or 1,0-vector) for each comparison.

For example, if I have a matrix of

```
M1 = [[1,2,3]
      [3,4,5]]

M2 = [[1,2],
      [3,4]]

result should be [[[False, False, False],
                   [True, False, False]],
                  [[False, False, False], 
                   [True, False, False]]]
```

Currently, I am using for loops which is tremendously slow when I have to repeat this operations many times (taking months). Hopefully, there is a vectorized way to do this. If not, what else can I do?

I am looking at `M_1` being (500, 3000000) and `M_2` being (500, 500) and repeated about 10000 times.

Comment: @Divakar sorry edited

Comment: Since this is a completely memory bound problem (in numexpr as shown by @Divakar or if Numba or Cython is used) , it would be good to know what you gonna do with this boolean array afterwards.

Comment: I don't believe you could plausibly actually need this.

Comment: Also a (500, 500, 3000000) bool matrix is almost 700 GiB. A bitwise representation reduces that to under 90 GiB, but means you can't use basic Numpy matrices.

Comment: @Veedrac Let me explain the setting to you then. The problem is to test face recognition algorithms in a database with 3million faces, with about 500 belonging to a person/identity on average. The test is: for each identity, I need to compute pairwise distances among the faces belonging to the same identity (intraclass) and compute pairwise distances between faces of the identity and faces of other identities (interclass). Then, ideally we should have the max_intraclass_distance < min_intraclass_distance. However, this is too strict. So I need to be able have some sort of tolerance of error.

Comment: for each threshold, i need to do a `M1 < M2`. This threshold is to be tweakable so I can have an idea of how good the algorithm is at different error tolerance. And yes, I do have memory problems now and I do not yet know how to do what i want in a more efficient way.

Comment: So what do the matrices represent, and what are `M` and `B`? (I get that `A` is the number of images.) This doesn't seem anything like how these things are normally done, which is to just calculate the accuracy; see standard papers for that.

Comment: @Veedrac A is a matrix of interclass features and B is a matrix of intraclass features. Just because other people do it in other ways (so called "standard") doesn't mean they are the best or "correct" way. Our production situation is dealing with millions of people and has a very low tolerance for errors. Papers on face recognition only deals with test case much smaller than that. Yes, papers do claim accuracy in the millions but when you read closer, you will notice their accuracy is at a high error tolerance (1%, 0.1%, etc). That percentage out of millions of people is too high.

Comment: @Veedrac Face recognition is in need of a wake-up call but sadly the media is always reporting it inaccurately and researchers are happy to get paid highly for producing their dubious results. See this for the relevant discussion if you are interested: https://github.com/wy1iu/sphereface/issues/98, one of the leading papers in this space.

Comment: @user136266 "A is a matrix" → no it isn't, it's a scalar. (???) Your opinions are fun and all, but they are not substitute for an argument: what are you doing and why are you doing it? You might think it's obvious why you have a 500x500 matrix, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @user136266 In particular, if you care about false positives more than false negatives, why not just give a false positive rate?

Comment: @Veedrac ok typo, they are just number of inter/intraclass features not matrix. my bad. It is probably not a good place to discuss here. Maybe we could chat elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173715/discussion-between-veedrac-and-user136266).

Answer (score 3):

For NumPy arrays, extend dims with `None/np.newaxis` such that the first axes are aligned, while the second ones are *spread* that lets them be compared in an elementwise fashion. Finally do the comparsion leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution -

```
M1[:,None,:] < M2[:,:,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: M1
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [20]: M2
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [21]: M1[:,None,:] < M2[:,:,None]
Out[21]: 
array([[[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]]])
```

For lists as inputs, use [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) and then compare -

```
In [42]: M1 = [[1,2,3],
    ...:       [3,4,5]]
    ...: 
    ...: M2 = [[1,2],
    ...:       [3,4]]

In [43]: np.expand_dims(M1, axis=1) < np.expand_dims(M2, axis=2)
Out[43]: 
array([[[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]]])
```

**Further boost**

Further boost upon leveraging [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data -

```
In [44]: import numexpr as ne

In [52]: M1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(500, 30000))

In [53]: M2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(500, 500))

In [55]: %timeit M1[:,None,:] < M2[:,:,None]
1 loop, best of 3: 3.32 s per loop

In [56]: %timeit ne.evaluate('M1e<M2e',{'M1e':M1[:,None,:],'M2e':M2[:,:,None]})
1 loop, best of 3: 1.53 s per loop
```